# could not find qtwebengineprocess.exe Кодировка пути к файлу

Tags: python-3.x, path, кириллица, decode, qtwebengine

Программа предназначена для работы в системах Windows.

Упакованная через `pip install` вылетает при запуске, с сообщением в консоли `could not find qtwebengineprocess.exe`, если у юзера на компе имя пользователя написано кириллицей.

Для понимания, если имя пользователя компа (учетная запись) на латиннице (**Pasha**), то прога будет работать:

```
C:\Users\Pasha\AppData\Local\Programs\ToonJoy_Animatics\PyQt5\Qt\bin\QtWebEngineProcess.exe
```

Но если имя пользователя на кириллице (**Паша**):

```
C:\Users\Паша\AppData\Local\Programs\ToonJoy_Animatics\PyQt5\Qt\bin\QtWebEngineProcess.exe
```

Программа падает при поиске **QtWebEngineProcess.exe** с уведомлением `could not find qtwebengineprocess.exe`. Разница в пути **Pasha** и **Паша**, кириллица и латинница. Явно дело в кодировке и путь с кракозябрами не обнаруживается.

**Вопрос:** где и как можно исправить/декодировать путь к файлу, если в коде программы и упаковщика он нигде явно не указывается?